# ubuntu terminal doesn't show more than 500 lines

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, lines

When I use a command that shows a lot of lines like "show exploits" in metasploit , it shows the last 500 lines and doesn't show the other lines at the top .. how can i see everything ?

Comment: This would typically be a feature of your terminal emulator. If you use the default gnome-terminal, you should be able to change this setting somewhere in the config menu for gnome-terminal. If you use tmux or something like that, it will have its own scrollback history.

Comment: Another option is to pipe the output of your command into `less`, which lets you navigate and search through thousands of lines of output. `show exploits | less`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume piping through `more` or `less` is not what you want? 
You can change the scroll back limit by going to Edit/Profile Preferences/Scrolling and increase the number of lines.